# Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer'

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode9, swift4

2 errors occur after migrating to swift 4.

First error:

> Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.

[image]

Second error:

> Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not [AVCaptureDevice].

[image]

How Should I correct these errors?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you just remove `if let ...` condition and changes

like simple

```
let cameraLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self.cameraSession)
```

And same for second error means you should use directly `videoDevices` no need to use `if let...` condition.

Comment: if i am writing 

let cameraLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self.cameraSession)

then i got error:

Cannot invoke initializer for type 'AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer' with an argument list of type '(session: AVCaptureSession, () -> ())'

Answer (score 2):

The initializer of `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` doesn't return an optional. Thus, the if condition is always true, and the if statement ist useless. You should remove the if and it's braces.